# Installer Oracle Server not allows to enter a value in the field

Tags: database, oracle-linux, oracle-database

I set up a server for home testing on Virtual Box. I can't enter the letters in the field "email", only numbers, how do I fix it? Thanks for any help.

[image: screen]